# Error while rosmake ethzasl_icp_mapper

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I downloaded the ethzasl_icp_mapping from ROS,
git clone https://github.com/ethz-asl/ethzasl_icp_mapping.git

rosdep install ethzasl_icp_mapping, it showed an error that map_msgs was missing. I get the package and then rosdep did not show any errors.

rosmake ethzasl_icp_mapper is giving the errors below.

### {-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
mkdir -p build
cd build && cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-fPIC" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=.. -DPYTHON_CUSTOM_TARGET=src ../upstream_src
CMake Error: The source directory "/home/sai/fuerte_workspace/ethzasl_icp_mapping/libnabo/upstream_src" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.

Also the folder /home/sai/fuerte_workspace/ethzasl_icp_mapping/libnabo/upstream_src is empty.

Please let me know what can be done.

Thanks ,
Sai

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/72997/error-while-rosmake-ethzasl_icp_mapper/) by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1935 on 2013-08-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks to Pomerleau, Francois for his reply on GitHub

please have a look at the node documentation on ROS:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/ethzasl_icp_mapping under the section Installation.
The dependency to map_msgs is also written there.

There are subdirectories from external git repositories to fetch. This is
why you need to use the flag --recursive. The command to clone is:

$ git clone --recursive git://github.com/ethz-asl/ethzasl_icp_mapping.git

---

Originally posted by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) with karma: 1935 on 2013-08-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0